# Is a discord bot classified as a web server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a google classroom discord bot and i needed to fill out an OAuth form. to do this it asked me what I was making so I put a web server. and then it asked me for a URI. does this mean I have to own my own website? or is a discord bot not a webserver.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If your discord bot does not serve at least one webpage, it's not a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any** OAuth2 Forms will require a redirectURI which they will append the confirmation code, or send it to. While a **Discord Bot** in itself is ***Not*** a Web Server, you can create one using your VPS's external IP (If you have one, but you generally get one per VM.) by following a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxLob6-8Sl0) to do so.

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/

> Redirect URLs are a critical part of the OAuth flow. After a user successfully authorizes an application, the authorization server will redirect the user back to the application with either an authorization code or access token in the URL. Because the redirect URL will contain sensitive information, it is critical that the service doesn’t redirect the user to arbitrary locations.

NOTE: I don't think that changing your option from Web Server to whatever will change a thing, if you want to use redirectURI, which is required for OAuth2, then make a Web Server and connect it to your Bot.

Comment: Glad to be of help @TravisC